# Question about how to read 如何

Tags: readings

Taking this sentence as an example:

> 納入した学費は、理由の如何｛を問わず/に関わらず｝返却しません。

I always have a hard time knowing how to read 如何; いか, いかが, even どう or いかん sometimes..

I've checked if the question was answered previously, I hope I didn't missed it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the sentence you gave it is functioning as a noun, so its reading is [如何]{いかん}.

> ❶［名］事の次第。なりゆき。ようす。「理由の―によっては」「事の成否は君の協力―による」

Source: [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/10232/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93/)

Recognizing from context the part of speech 如何 is functioning as (noun, adverb, adjectival verb) is helpful as a first step. Also, recognizing if it is part of a set phrase e.g. [如何]{どう}あっても, [如何]{どう}致しまして, [如何]{いかが}なものか, [如何]{いかん}せん, [如何]{いか}に should get you there in most cases.